# Round a number down (not half down)

Tags: numbers, rounding

I'm looking for a round mode like *PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN* but always down :

```
$number = 76.5 // I want 76
$number = 76.6 // I want 76
$number = 77.0 // I want 77
$number = 0.0165 // I want 0.0160 
$number = 0.0166 // I want 0.0160
$number = 0.0170 // I want 0.0170
```

There is a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the floor function, e.g.:

```
floor(76.5) = 76
```

But for rounding decimals to a decimal place you will need to multiply/divide, e.g.:

```
floor(0.0165 * 1000) / 1000 = 0.016
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php